# Db2 constraint query giving error

Tags: database, db2, constraints

I am trying to add following constraint to my DB2 table but it gives error.

```
    ALTER TABLE Table_name ADD CONSTRAINT VALID_BINDING 
    CHECK((LOWER(REQ_BINDING) IN ('http-post','http-redirect'))
    AND ((LOWER(RESP_BINDING) IN ('http-post','http-redirect')));
```

**Error stack trace**

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "',
'http-redirect')))".  Expected tokens may include:  ")".  SQLSTATE=42601

SQL0104N  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "','http-redirect')))".  Expected tokens may include:  ")                               ".

Explanation: 

A syntax error in the SQL statement or the input command string 
for the SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD procedure was detected at the specified 
token following the text "<text>".  The "<text>" field indicates 
the 20 characters of the SQL statement or the input command 
string for the SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD procedure that preceded the 
token that is not valid.  

 As an aid, a partial list of valid tokens is provided in the 
SQLERRM field of the SQLCA as "<token-list>".  This list assumes 
the statement is correct to that point.  

 The statement cannot be processed.
```

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AND operator in DB2 constraints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574840/and-operator-in-db2-constraints)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parentheses missed.

```
ALTER TABLE Table_name ADD CONSTRAINT VALID_BINDING 
    CHECK((LOWER(REQ_BINDING) IN ('http-post','http-redirect'))
    AND ((LOWER(RESP_BINDING) IN ('http-post','http-redirect'))));
```