# AND operator in DB2 constraints

Tags: database, db2, operator-keyword

I am trying to add following constraint to my DB2 table but it gives error.

```
ALTER TABLE Table_name ADD CONSTRAINT VALID_BINDING 
CHECK((LOWER(REQ_BINDING) IN ('http-post','http-redirect'))
AND ((LOWER(RESP_BINDING) IN ('http-post','http-redirect')));
```

Is this a valid query. Can I use AND operator in it?

Comment: Why do you ask the same question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573964/db2-constraint-query-giving-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it about parentheses?

```
ALTER TABLE Table_name ADD CONSTRAINT VALID_BINDING 
CHECK(
    LOWER(REQ_BINDING) IN ('http-post','http-redirect') AND 
    LOWER(RESP_BINDING) IN ('http-post','http-redirect')
);
```